# Is "burning a bounty" acceptable behavior?

Tags: discussion, bounty, sock-puppets

Question [How do I scrollIntoView a DOM Range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77421214/how-do-i-scrollintoview-a-dom-range) has two answers, one with a score of +3/-1 (the answer is mine) and eligible for half the bounty since the OP doesn't seem to be interested in awarding the bounty manually.

The question was not edited throughout the bounty period, indicating a lack of interest by the OP.

One minute before the final expiration of the bounty, a user with 1 rep posts a (not an) answer, OP awards the bounty, the person deletes the answer. I expect that it was the OP who operated the other account based on this answer:

> Burning the bounty. None of the answers are good enough.

[image: screenshot of the answer]

Is this behavior acceptable?

What could I do about it?

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call the answer cryptic. IMO OP couldn't have made it more obvious what they were doing if they tried. Maybe they assumed deleted answers aren't visible to anyone?

Comment: @MegaIng OP has > 20k rep so they know how deleted answers work and the exact rules of bounty (and how to circumvent them).

Comment: The "2 upvotes gets you half the bounty" is a pretty poor rule that leads to some pretty poor outcomes in my opinion. Although given it is a rule, circumventing it is probably an abuse.

Comment: ... or at least, there should be a way for the bounty poster to choose to accept nothing.

Comment: I'd partially agree, @DavidW, but if *others* have voted on the answer, then it's been proven to be useful/helpful. Bountying doesn't guarantee a user they will get an answer specific to *their* needs; sometimes (often) users don't tell the true picture and because bounties draw additional attention, it's not noticed until that attention is drawn.

Comment: Does the 1-rep user get to keep the reputation from the bounty, or does it disappear with the deletion of the answer? I think "burning" means the reputation disappears; please clarify (since you know the rules).

Comment: @ThomA I'm not convinced voting on bountied questions is hugely correlated with usefulness largely due to the extra attention - probably a lot of people glancing at an answer and saying "that looks plausible". Voting on regular questions is better I think because most of the voters probably have a similar problem. I agree that "Bountying doesn't guarantee a user they will get an answer specific to their needs" but don't really see why that means that a bounty should be partly auto-accepted

Comment: @DavidW half bounty rule looks well thought out to me. There is a minimum +2 precondition so opinion of people other than the op is counted. Then there's users who ask offer bounty but not willing to communicate properly (just read through comments on that question).

Comment: @anatolyg if the answer had a score of 3 or more and was visible for 60+ days the user would keep the reputation from the bounty. In this case though the answer was 0 score so the rep would be lost. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067

Comment: If the answer was undeleted then the reputation would the re-added to the sockpuppet, @anatolyg . (Of course, it's not going to be, but that's a moot point.)

Comment: @SalmanA I'm OK with it as a default - it guards against people who offer a bounty then lose interest and don't bother to award it. However, definitely think there should be a way to not award the bounty without sock-puppet accounts. The decision this user took seems pretty reasonable - it's only an abuse because it's using dodgy tricks to get round the system.

Comment: Definitely abuse worthy of suspension. That part has been handled, but dunno if something can be done about the bounty rep that you didn't get because of that abuse. Do you care about that? If so, I'd guess the only avenue is to contact SO employees.

Comment: @M-- someone flagged it for me. I won't contest about the points though. I want to thank everyone for their feedback.

Comment: I appreciate I'm talking on behalf of someone else here, I don't think they meant they "burned the bounty" in the same way, @Tom . Their bounty was "burned" as it wasn't awarded to anyone, by themselves or the system. The scenario this question is about is that it was *explicitly* awarded to a sock puppet to *avoid* the bounty being awarded to someone else (automatically). The scenarios are very different.

Comment: @ThomA No, *"I also burned the bounty, as I don't want to stimulate giving A.I. generated answers. So, indeed, there are cases where burning bounties can be justifiable"* doesn't read like *"The bounty was pointless, because I only got A.I. answers"*. At least not to me.

Comment: It doesn't read like it, but if you look at the actual bounties the user in question offered recently (both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77315782/2029983)), @Tom , it gives you the full picture. There aren't any instances where the user has done what is described in the post here.

Comment: Notwithstanding anything to do with the bounty itself, this looks like blatant sock-puppetry to me.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Sounds like abuse of the system; I would flag for moderator attention with a custom moderator flag. <strike>With only a limited screenshot I can't properly infer, but if nothing else</strike> Looking at the Q&A in its entirety, and the timings in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77421214/timeline), I would suggest that the user created a new account, posted a bad answer to their own question, gave it the bounty (which is against the rules as you can't have a sock puppet interact with your other accounts), and then deleted the answer.

The moderator team likely can't do anything about the bounty being given to a rogue account, but they can nuke it and warn the user.

If you want a suggestion on what to say, flag the answer, and then state something like:

> It appears the author of the question has created a sock puppet to award the bounty to, to avoid giving it to another user. The answer that the bounty is awarded to is nonsense (it just states the answers aren't "good enough"), the bounty was awarded almost immediately after it was posted, and the answer was deleted very quickly afterwards as well. This all suggests these actions were undertaken by the same individual.

Digging further into this user, this is not the first time they have done this, I found a prior [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77465643/2029983) that occurred quite recently and that account was nuked. Most likely, therefore, the user has been warned about these actions before.

Comment: Maybe the user nuked the sock-puppet? If I involved myself in such trickery, that's what I would do.

Comment: Interesting finding about the other bounty in which op did exactly the same.

Comment: @SalmanA - Indeed. Seems to be "just" those two (of the user's 20 non-deleted questions, anyway). Two is two too many of course.

Comment: There is no need to speculate. [They themselves described it beforehand.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166172/explicit-do-not-award-bounty-button#comment1318628_166172)

Answer (score 56):

Given that it would not be possible to 'burn a bounty' with a single account, this is abuse of using multiple accounts. You are not allowed to use multiple accounts for anything that you cannot do with a single account. This includes but is not limited to voting on your own posts or awarding bounties on your own posts (even if just to 'burn' the bounty).

I would suggest raising a moderator flag so that appropriate disciplinary action may be taken.

Answer (score 14):

On one hand, this is a clear abuse of the system, since they're using a second account to do something they can't do otherwise.

On the other hand, I just had *my* bounty (which I placed on other's question) auto-awarded to a non-useful answer, which doesn't really answer the question, but just happens to satisfy OP by apparently solving their underlying issue (so the question was an XY-problem).

So while I think the user in question was justly banned for this, I also think that the auto-award system is somewhat flawed (but I don't know how to fix it, since adding a "don't award" button could be prone to abuse).

Comment: strongly related (declined) feature request: [Explicit "do not award bounty" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166172/165773)

Comment: @gnat Yeah, just having that button would be prone to abuse. I'm not sure what would be a good solution.

Comment: Third solution. Don't post bounties on XY problem questions ;)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar It not always possible to distinguish them, if Y can be a valid goal in itself. In my case, the question effectively asks "how do I print UTF8 to the terminal", and the answer proceeds to explain how to print UTF16 instead. The asker accepts, because apparently they just want Unicode, and don't really care if it's UTF8 or not, while I want exactly UTF8.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Actually, if the bounty is non-refundable, it's very unlikely that a _"Don't award it"_ button would be subject to abuses. And if one does so, it would be a very rare edge-case for which a _"flag for moderator attention"_ would be worth :)

Comment: Well, edit the question to ask how you get utf-16 in terminal and ask another one where you ask about utf-8. That does not solve the problem with the awarded bounty, but it would at least not confuse people that land on the question looking for solution.

Comment: @Fareanor Mhm. I'd rather have gold-badge holders vote whether the answer is worthy in case of a dispute, since mods are not SMEs. But there's not much sense in discussing this, we all know SE isn't gonna implement any of this any time soon. :/

Comment: Maybe increasing the votes limit would help. Two upvotes is really low and while in most cases you can also downvote answers if they don't answer the question for auto rewarding I would expect a bit more votes.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar - In this case it wouldn’t have prevented an answer with 12 upvotes submitted after the bounty was started from being half awarded. The user who offered the bounty, abused the bounty system, if they were unhappy with the answer they received improving the quality of the question and offering another bounty is always acceptable behavior. Avoiding the half award because the answers they received were not up to their “standard” is unacceptable.

Comment: @SecurityHound I am fine with that. Problem is that just two upvotes )(or three if OP can downvote) could justify awarding the bounty when the answers are really subpar. This is even worse in the era of AI where AI answers look good and people uncritically upvote them. Anyway, I do have a problem with someone abusing the system even when the system is not exactly perfect.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar - it is our responsibility to downvote and flag answers that are subpar and in clear cases of the use of AI to generate the content flag the contribution. Of course nothing we could have done would have prevented the author from violating the rules with regards to having two accounts